# Using sed to match between two strings

Tags: regex, sed

example string: `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/test/`

I need the output to be the volume name, `Macintosh HD`

I've tried the following:

```
echo "/Volumes/testVolume/test/" | sed 's/\/Volumes\/\(.*\)\//\1/g'
```

but the output is: `testVolume/test`

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
sed 's#/Volumes/\([^/]*\)/.*#\1#'
```

Instead of using `/` to mark the search and replace expressions, you could use any other character as well. `#` is a commonly used character if your search or replace expressions contain the character `/` in them.

```
$ sed 's#/Volumes/\([^/]*\)/.*#\1#' <<< "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/test/"
Macintosh HD
```